# Early exit function in Typescript with return cause Eslint 'no useless return' error

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a Typescript function like below. It is used to check for validation, if failed exit out of the submit function. However, ESLint is giving me 'no-useless-return' error. Is this ESLint at fault or my code quality is bad? Can you give me some advice.

```
submit() {
  if (!this.checkValidate()) return
  // TODO
}
```

Comment: In the function you posed, the conditional return is the last statement of the code and is useless. But when you replace the comment with actual code then this return is no longer useless and the warning should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your checkValidate function beforehand and if its valid then call the submit function.

```
submit() {//TODO}
if (this.checkValidate()) {
  submit() 
}
```